# git push with access token

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push my code, make many tries and facing diffrent issues.

> git push origin master

```
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls
 for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://$$$$AccessToken$$$$$@github.com/$$username$$/ecommerce.git/'
```

I tried `git push origin main`. and I got this issue.
error: src refspec main does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://$$GithubAccessToken$$@github.com/$$username$$/ecommerce.git'

how to push code using github Access Token.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+remote%3A+Support+for+password+authentication+was+removed+on+August+13%2C+2021

Answer (score 0):

don't use your login password, just use a access token, you can generate on this page https://github.com/settings/tokens/new, check access as you need. and generate token. don't forget to save generated token first, because that is one time view only. and try login with generated token.